# New-ItemClone Error through SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell, item-clones

I recently tried using New-ItemClone command on SPE and encountered this error:

> System.AggregateException,Cognifide.PowerShell.Commandlets.Data.Clones.NewItemCloneCommand

These are the codes used:

```
$master = Get-Item .
$destination = Get-Item -Path "master:\content"   
$siteName = "myNewSite"

$newSite = New-ItemClone $master -Destination $destination -Name $siteName -Recurse
```

[image]

I'm using Sitecore 8 update 2 and SPE 4.7.2

Any clue what this might be? I'm new to using Sitecore cloning. Is there a particular item that can't be cloned? I've searched for documentations but can't find a specific one for this error.

Comment: Could you check your Sitecore logs and search for errors? (there is an error in some `item:saving` handler)

Comment: Do you have custom events in the `item:saving`?

Comment: Yes, we have a custom event on the item:saving. I'll look into it more and come back to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking into my solution, I found out that this error is due to a custom item:saving event code that was being called when executing New-ItemClone command. Putting a condition when this New-ItemClone is executing fixes the problem